# Rewrite URL within Google Analytics 4 to remove Guid

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We currently use Universal Analytics(UA) and are moving over to Google Analytics 4(GA4).
We have 5 websites under the same domain. We use Google Tag Manager.

One of our websites has a guid within it URL. We created a filter within our UA account to remove this to stay under the daily URL limit:

Universal Analytics Advanced filter

[image: 1]

From:
https://example.website.org.uk/survey/1/ec007993-1fe4-4a88-b896-03bc03246073

To:
https://example.website.org.uk/survey/1

GA4 does not have any advanced filtering options at the moment. This is causing the property to go over the daily limit and reporting values as '(Other)'.

Are there any ways to rewrite URL's for GA4?

**Update**:
We created a new GA4 configuration tag for the specific website.

[image: GA4 config tag with a variable overriding the 'page_location' field via JavaScript]

As mentioned in the answer by BNazaruk we overwrote the 'page_location' field via JavaScript. The following image provide an example of a URL being split and returned to override the 'page_location' field.

[image: Custom javascript that splits the current pages URL and returns it]

Comment: Looking forward to getting an answer. FYI, I posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73991772/write-a-search-and-replace-filter-in-google-analytics-4-ga4 (I wasn't aware of your question at the time. Cross-linking here in case one gets an answer before the other :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea behind GA4 is to make it cheaper to maintain for Google. They got rid of the costly regex-based data pre-processing. They kept only the most trivial filters that you can really only barely call filters. Probably only to not make it seem as if filters were removed completely. But they were removed completely, effectively.

You have three options now:

1. You're not supposed to have sensitive information (like guid) in your url. GA is not the only place you track it in. Any pixel you install will pass this data. You backend access logs will contain these ids. This is a front-end architecture mistake in vast majority of cases. Fixing it properly will remove the need to replace it in analytics.
2. GTM can override the location and path dimensions very easily. Here's how:
   [image]
   You override the three dimensions just like that and you're all set. You will do it through three CJS variables. Two of them will just take document.location.href, sanitize it as you need and return. One will take the document.referrer, sanitize it and return. Or just return the referrer if it detects that the referrer doesn't contain your domain.

The only problem here is that you will have to do this overridal for every GA4 tag due to how Google made it impossible to use a config variable as we used to in UA tags. This is why we try to keep GA4 tags to an absolute minimum with JS routers and regex tables.

3. Finally, you can do the replace during ETL if you use something else for analysis, but it will still leave the sensitive data in GA, so this may or may not be useful depending on why you need to sanitize the data.

Comment: Thanks for extensive answer. I'll award the bounty, although I was hoping for something more on the GA4 panel.
Like @Patrice Chalin in his linked question, I'm more interested in something else, mostly to have a better reports that would aggregate all the product URLs into one, etc.