# Write a search-and-replace filter in Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

How can I write the equivalent of a Universal Analytics (UA) **[search-and-replace filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834) for Google Analytics 4** (GA4)?

For example, what would be the steps for creating a GA4 "filter" that prefixes page view paths from a specific host (`somehost.org`) with a given string (`/from-somehost`)?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219098/rewrite-url-within-google-analytics-4-to-remove-guid

Answer (score 0):

I gave a more elaborate answer to this in the linked similar question.

In your case, you can just pull both dimensions: the hostname and the path to your exploration report and then filter them as you see fit.

Many data scientists and analysts find GA/GA4 UI limiting, so they extract the data to BQ and then either query raw data there, or ETL it further and use much more powerful BI tools to build dashboards and conduct ad-hoc analysis.